# Como fazer o NetBeans reconhecer a sintaxe do ES2015?

Tags: netbeans, sintaxe, ecmascript-6

Como usar o [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) com o [ES2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)? Já fiz alguns testes com a versão 8.0.1 e 8.0.2 do NetBeans, mas não reconhece a sintaxe nova: `let`, `const`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que o Netbeans atual não suporte ECMAScript 6 (ECMAScript 2015), mas isto está previsto para a [versão 8.2](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB82#ECMAScript_6_Support) do Netbeans.

Se estiver disposto, baixe a [versão de desenvolvimento](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) do Netbeans e dê uma olhada :).

Answer (score 0):

A versão de desenvolvimento do Netbeans já suporta ECMA6.

http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/

Comment: Responder... responde. Mas é a mesma coisa dita pelo Dherik.

Comment: A resposta do Dherik não dá certeza. É um talvez... Eu estou usando a versão de desenvolvimento do Netbeans e afirmando que funciona com ECMA6.